# how to access facebook data using Apl as facepager?

Tags: java, data-analysis, bigdata

I have to access the Facebook data, How to access using API ?
I used `facepager` for fetch a data but it doesn't fetching, why ?

Anyother way to get a fb data ???
[image]

Comment: format, remove irrelevant info and add image embedded

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the base path to `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/` since Facebook shuts down old API versions. Then load a preset and adjust the settings to your needs.

For further information see the section "Current Status" on https://github.com/strohne/Facepager. And check out the help which is built into Facepager (click Help Button).

BTW: we just opened a [Group on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/groups/136224396995428/) for getting help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is other way to get data:

1. Select node
2. then click on Fetch data button.

   That's mean select minecraft row then click button.